# How to Break out of time.sleep() when while loop condition is met

Tags: python, time, while-loop, alarm, python-datetime

I'm making an alarm that adjusts according to traffic. After messing around a bit, I decided it would be best for the program to get data from the API every 15 minutes or so. However, I noticed that if the while loop condition was met while time.sleep() was active, it wouldn't break till the full duration of time.sleep() ended. Is there any way to have it break when the condition is met, even during time.sleep()? Thanks in advance!

```
while datetime.datetime.now() < self.wakeuptime: #refers to alarm time

            resp = requests.get(url=url, params=param)
            data = json.loads(resp.content)
            simplifiedtime = datetime.datetime.strptime(data["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["departure_time"]["text"], "%I:%M%p").time()
            #gets suggested departure time from api

            combinedsimplifiedtime=datetime.datetime.combine(today, simplifiedtime)
            self.wakeuptime = combinedsimplifiedtime  - datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
            #resets wakeuptime value depending on api
            self.timetogo = combinedsimplifiedtime
            print self.wakeuptime
            time.sleep(900)
            #waits 15 minutes and checks again until wakeuptime
```

Comment: Subtract `datetime.now()` from `self.wakeuptime`; if the difference is less than 900 seconds, only sleep for the difference.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! @Ryan! The only thing is I want it to check for the 15 minute interval, as the difference will be more than 900 seconds, I want the program to continually check for traffic every 15 minutes unless the while loop condition is met.

Comment: … if the difference *isn’t* less than 900 seconds, sleep for 900 seconds.

Comment: Oh! Great solution as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use another while loop to check the current time much more frequently than the one that updates from the API. Instead of `time.sleep(900)` you can do:

```
start_pause = datetime.datetime.now()
while (datetime.datetime.now()-start_pause).seconds < 900 \
    and datetime.datetime.now() < self.wakeuptime:
    time.sleep(1)
```

This will still only run the outer loop after 900 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The only problem is I do need the loop to break even if it's during that 900 second interval. Is there anyway to have it wait for 900 seconds but stop in the middle if the while loop condition is met?

Comment: @JackGruber I updated the answer, it should do that now if I understand your objective correctly

Comment: To place this one in your existing one in place of the call to `sleep`

Comment: oh okay will try now.

Comment: It worked! thank you so much! I wish I could upvote 10000 times but I don't have enough reputation yet. Any chance you could explain why that worked over my time.sleep call?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, happy to help! The difference is that the sleep call doesn't check the while condition until it completes, but the inner while method checks each second if the condition is met while also waiting for  15 minutes to get back to the API check. Also, if this answered your question, you could mark it as accepted with the checkmark so others will know it has been answered.

Comment: Thank you so much! Done! If you could upvote the question I'd really appreciate it as I am trying to build reputation.